# Iterating data with for loop and switch case

Tags: php

I am having a problem with iterating data. My `for` loop is a bit strange. I am matching property->value and sending those to DB. But before that I am having a `Undefined offset: 84` I think this error pops up likely when data is null. Though data is not null because I debugged it. The problem start with when I write `for` and `switch case` loop.

```
        $getTR = $path->query("table[@class='bgc_line']/tr/td");
        foreach($getTR as $tr){
            if ($tr->length == 2) {
                $route = $path>query("//table[@class='bgc_line']/tr/td[1]");
                foreach ($route as $td1) {
                    $property[] = trim($td1->nodeValue);
                }

                $route = $path->query("//table[@class='bgc_line']/tr/td[2]");
                foreach ($route as $td2) {
                    $value[] = trim($td2->nodeValue);
                }
            }
        }


        for ($a=0; $a < count($property); $a++) { 
            switch ($property[$a]) {
                    case '物件名':
                        $database['building_name'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '販売価格':
                        $database['price'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '専有面積':
                        $database['extend'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '所在地':
                        $database['address'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '総戸数':
                        $database['total_house'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '間取り':
                        $database['rooms'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '竣工時期':
                        $database['cons_finish'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '管理会社':
                        $database['company_name'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case '入居時期':
                        $database['entry'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    case 'バルコニー面積':
                        $database['balcony'] = $value[$a];
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong with the `for` and `switch case` and if you need to see head of code, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yLuF.png) I share an image.

Comment: Check how many elements are in the `$value` array, you could put something like `if (count($property) != count($value)) echo "something";`

Comment: You should try if else in for loop :)

Comment: but when I do same scrape with DOMDocument and use foreach instead of for loop. Then there is nor problem. When I do it with Xpath and using For then this problem occure. For example: like this; https://imgur.com/a/D2G0w4T @NigelRen

Comment: could you give me an example for if else in for loop? @ParvejAlam

Comment: So stick with your other way - in this version you are using 2 XPath expressions and hoping that the data matches.  This can be risky (IMHO).

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but with Xpath I can easyly find out the data. DOMd is a bit diffucult for me. So in the end I am trying to fix this problem and try to learn why is this happening. @NigelRen

Comment: Have you checked if the two XPath expressions return the same number of items?

Comment: you mean property and value? Hm, not yet look it. And do you think using if else fix this? not using swtich case? @NigelRen

Comment: Stick with a switch, but I just mean the number of values (i.e. `count()`) as in the first comment I left.

Comment: and no property returns with 72 and value is returns with 52... But why there is no problem with DOMdoc? @NigelRen

Comment: by the way,  is there any way to skip this error? Because I know i am getting the data but the error stops the loop... @NigelRen

Comment: You should investigate more about why you're getting different numbers of elements in the two arrays. Because the two arrays may not correspond properly, and you're assigning the wrong values to the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$value` array is shorter than the `$property` array, so when you get to a property that has no corresponding value, you get an error when trying to access `$value[$a]`.

Use the minimum of `count($property)` and `count($value)` as the limit of the loop, so you don't go past the end of `$value`.

```
    $limit = min(count($property), count($value));
    for ($a=0; $a < $limit; $a++) { 
        switch ($property[$a]) {
        case '物件名':
            $database['building_name'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '販売価格':
            $database['price'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '専有面積':
            $database['extend'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '所在地':
            $database['address'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '総戸数':
            $database['total_house'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '間取り':
            $database['rooms'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '竣工時期':
            $database['cons_finish'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '管理会社':
            $database['company_name'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case '入居時期':
            $database['entry'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        case 'バルコニー面積':
            $database['balcony'] = $value[$a];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added somemore explanation, does it help?